# namespace constants

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an ideal way to namespace some constants to access later in my code. Ideally the constants will be two layers deep where the first layer is the namespace for the entire project. Let's call that `Foo`. The second layer is the class which the constants are representing, let's call it `Bar`. Is the best way to implement something like this using the following?

```
var Foo = Foo || {};
Foo.Bar = {
  CONST_A: 1,
  CONST_B: 220130324,
  ...
}
```

Is the best way to retrieve the value of CONST_A the following:

`Foo.Bar.CONST_A`? Is there a way to write a helper method so I don't have to use the fully qualified namespace in order to access the constant? What's the best way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes and Yes and Yes.

Comment: "var Foo = Foo || {};" is pointless, "var Foo={};" is better (not hiding a potential ref error without fixing it), but why use Foo at all instead of hopping to Bar?

Comment: inside a function using "constants", you can shorten the path to a single dot: var C=Foo.Bar; ... alert(C.CONST_A); you also _can_ (read shouldn't) use with(Foo.Bar){  alert( CONST_A ); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common way of handling these.  Having a shorthand helper is not as useful, as it defeats the purpose of having a namespaced constant.