# Is there a JavaScript DEFINE directive equivalent?

Tags: javascript, php

Inside a php file I have a script such as this snippet:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#tabs_<?php echo $keyCode ?>").tabs();

  var x = document.getElementById("bkhmode_<?php echo $keyCode ?>");
  var mode = x.value;
  setcont_<?php echo $keyCode ?>(mode);
});
</script>
```

I want to remove this piece of code along with many other lines like it into a separate JS file to take advantage of caching BUT I have been unable to find the equivalent of a DEFINE command to allow me to replace the **php echo**.

I would like to

```
  DEFINE KEY_CODE = 'somevalue';
```

then the snippet would  look something like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#tabs_KEY_CODE").tabs();
  var x = document.getElementById("bkhmode_KEY_CODE");
  var mode = x.value;
  setcont_KEY_CODE(mode);
});
</script>
```

Most languages allow for this but I have been unable to find anything equivalent in JavaScript.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This should help: [`[javascript] dynamic function name`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+dynamic+function+name)

Comment: There is this idea of pseudo namespace constants in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257291/namespace-constants) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set variables to the global window namespace, although it is considered bad practice as it can interfere with other programs, so be careful.

```
window.KEY_CODE = 'somevalue';

$(function() {
    $("#tabs_" + window.KEY_CODE); // Will escape local scope.
});
```

That should work, although it's common practice to do this with an IIFE.

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined) {
    $("#tabs_" + window.KEY_CODE); // Will escape local scope.
})(window, window.document, window.jQuery);
```

That helps resolve a lot of namespace issues because they're explicitly defined in the local scope.

---

You can also use global variables to run a function.
If your function is declared outside of an IIFE (i.e. you've just run it in a global namespace), it's appended to the window element as well. For instance, these are equivalents.

```
function foo(a)
{
    console.log("foo" + a);
}

foo("bar"); // prints "foobar"
window.foo("bar2"); // prints "foobar2"
window['foo']("bar3"); // prints "foobar3"
```

This is because the browser will assume you're calling `window.foo` if the local variable `foo` is undefined. `window['foo']` is an identical way of calling `window.foo`; it accesses the `window` object, but using a string. So, with that in mind, we can accomplish your variable function call.

```
window.KEY_CODE = 'somevalue';

window.func_somevalue = function(a) {
    console.log("somevalue = " + a);
};

window.func_othervalue = function(a) {
    console.log("othervalue = " + a);
}

// prints "somevalue = Hello."
window['func_' + window.KEY_CODE]("Hello.");
```

You can do this with other objects.

```
window.KEY_CODE = 'somevalue';

(function(window, document, $, undefined) {
    $("#tabs_" + window.KEY_CODE); // Will escape local scope.

    var keys = {
        'somevalue' : function(a) { console.log(a); },
        'othervalue' : function() { console.log('other'); }
    };

    keys[window.KEY_CODE]("Hello.");
})(window, window.document, window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Jaw.sh:  This is an excellent suggestion but if there were to be say 15 possible values of KEY_CODE there would have to also be 15 separate versions of the function.  That is not a bad thing as that is what is currently happening inside the PHP code.  However using namespace globals would necessitate coding them all individually.  I think I need to more closely examine the basic concept here.  Too bad as a DEFINE DIRECTIVE has been a basic concept ever since I began programming.  Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I definitely have seen what you're describing in live code, but yeah, less than ideal. There's more efficient ways of accomplishing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the feature "new Function(args, body)" . Body may be a string or read from external file by readFileSync etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).